# Hyundai 2009 EPS malfuntion and starting issue

Tags: hyundai

I have an Hyundai I20 2009 model, recently and only when engine is at temp the car would battle to start, and when it starts the EPS light comes on and the revs go up and down. If I switch it off and try again it starts immediately and all appears to be normal. Then after a few km's the issue reappears again. This does not happen when the car is cold. Is this a sensor issue or what, please advise. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!